# Android. Any method inside onBindViewHolder executes repeatedly when I change model

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm using `recyclerView` with `databinding`.
It works fine, but when I'm trying to change binding model inside `onBindViewHolder` method I get a strange behavior: that method executes repeatedly.
Here is my `adapter`:

```
public class TasksLevelAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<RealmArticle, TasksLevelAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String TAG = "MYAPP";

    protected TasksLevelAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<RealmArticle> data, Activity mActivity) {
        super(data, true);
        setHasStableIds(true);
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        RowRecyclerviewMainBinding itemBinding =
                RowRecyclerviewMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final RealmArticle obj = getItem(position);
        int idTask = obj.getIdTask();
        holder.data = obj;
        holder.bind(obj);
        Log.e(TAG, new Date().getTime() + "");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { // - when I add this handler I'm getting it called repeatedly
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                        .executeTransaction(trans -> obj.setItemsCount("111"));
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return getItem(index).getIdTaskart();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final RowRecyclerviewMainBinding binding;
        private RealmArticle data;
        public MyViewHolder(RowRecyclerviewMainBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
        public void bind(RealmArticle obj) {
            binding.setObj(obj);
            binding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I remove `handler` inside `onBindViewHolder`, `Log.e` executes only once.

Why methods inside `OnbindViewHolder` executes repeatedly when I change a model? And how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your adapter with auto-update enabled:

```
super(data, true);
```

Within your posted `Runnable` you change the data of the bound object and thus an update is triggered. This is the reason `onBindViewHolder()` is called again.

Using auto-update and databinding together seems to be a little redundant. If `RealmArticle` is a databinding observable, it might be possible to not use auto-update for updates. So just disable `updateOnModification`.

```
super(data, true, false);
```